# Multiple lines data to show in TextBox / Label

Tags: jquery, html

I have to diplay data which can be in single line or multiple line (fetching from database). I tried using textbox but its size can't change dynamically , also i used label but for multiple line it shows all data in a single line instead to be broken in to multiple lines . Need some suggestions or solutions.

Comment: Use textarea if you're using jquery and html

Comment: Sorry @PragneshChauhan but i am on the way what could be best solution , as of now the code is just to get data and display on to label or textbox .

Answer (score 0):

For the multiline data, you probably need to us `nl2br`:

```
$text = nl2br(htmlentities($row['text']));
echo "<textbox>$text</textbox>";
```

Comment: Is it possible to put label which can break into multiple lines depending on fetched data .

Comment: You can use `nl2br` on any data that you're putting into the HTML. It will turn the newlines in the data into HTML `<BR>` tags, and you'll get multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

jquery [autosize](https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize) pluggin will be helpful for you. put your text in textarea and apply autosize. It will increase of decrease the length of textarea according to the content.